# Complex association from other models

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have four models

```
class RestaurantSpecialPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :restaurant
  belongs_to :stock
end

class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stock_prices, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :restaurant_special_prices, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :restaurants, through: :stock_prices
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :stock_prices, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :restaurant_special_prices, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :stocks, through: :stock_prices
  has_many :stocks_with_special_prices, through: :restaurant_special_prices, source: :stock
end

class StockPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :restaurant
  belongs_to :stock
end
```

I want to create association between restaurant special price and stock price so that I can get original price of a stock how can I associate both of them what is best way. I know I can get the record like this

```
special = RestaurantSpecialPrice.last
StockPrice.where(restaurant: special.restaurant, stock: special.restaurant)
```

and I also can do this via joins and includes but I want this through a proper associations.

Comment: on which object you want to be able to get the original price? Your associations are wide enough, and I don't see any spot, from which you can't get to any other one - why more associations?

Comment: for special object I want original price.

Comment: for which object? give me that object. Is it `Restaurant.first`, or is it `Stock.last` or any else? Also, what is original price - is it stock price?

Comment: I want stock price for RestaurantSpecialPrice.first with association

Answer (score 0):

> I want stock price for `RestaurantSpecialPrice.first` with association

You already have such association:

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stock_prices, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Use it:

```
Restaurant.first.stock_prices
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I want associations between RestaurantSpecialPrice and StockPrice as I mentioned I want RestaurantSpecialPrice.first.stock_price

Comment: @AsnadAtta so what, do you want `has_many` along with `has_one`?